# Binding java Library Xamarin.Android

Tags: java, c#, android, binding, xamarin.android

It's been two days that I seek on every forum, Docs, tuto, Blog etc..for an answer.

I began an Android app for my internship I develop it in xamarin C# because I don't know Java. Until recently everything was fine but now I need to integrate an SDK to use a POS (point of sale) with the app but this library is written in Java and I can't bind it with xamarin even if follow the docs or the tutor (I can't even debug).

There's someone here who already successfully bind a library which can help me?

I reached the point where I'm trying to learn quickly java to rewrite all the app.

here is the link to the SDK I need to integrate: https://github.com/sumup/sumup-android-sdk

Comment: my friend @AdamPedley writes this https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-xamarin-android-binding-library/

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'd already seen this and it wasn't helpful :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to consume Java libraries with Xamarin.Android projects. I used it to bind printer's Android SDK which was written completely in Java. At the end, you will produce .DLL that you can use and reference in any C# project.

However, I would recommend you to learn about .JAR bindings first.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

After that you can take a look at simple example of binding a .JAR to be sure what steps are needed.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Also, bear in mind a lot of things can go wrong during this process.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/